# Problems with Xcode Syntax Highlighting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, syntax, syntax-highlighting

In Xcode 3.2.1 I have this problem where it stops highlighting Objects in purple, and such. For example:

[image]

In that example, NSAutoreleasePool, pool, img, size, width and height should be highlighted, however, they are not. Here is a screenshot of what that looks like.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: Also, code sense isn't showing correct options.

Comment: Have you imported the `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` header (not that I'm sure it makes any difference...)?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, on top of that I'm using Cocoa Touch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: code loses syntax coloring ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring)

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. I had similar issues, and have documented a general solution (that doesn't involve continually restarting Xcode!)... See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245076/123632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is often glitchy for me in similar ways.  Restarting xcode often clears up the issue.  Also, sometimes a missing semi-colon or curly brace will keep codeSense and highlighting from working as you want it to.  Try Opt-B (build)  to see if you have any errors that could be causing this.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I had to rebuild the code sense index and restart Xcode.

Comment: Sometimes this does not help. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring/

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that opening projects from the XCode welcome screen causes this issue. If I dismis the welcome screen and then go file open (or file open recent) and open the project that way the syntax highlighting works