# Xcode Code Sense horribly broken?

Tags: xcode, codesense

Ever since I started using Xcode, I've experienced extremely annoying problems with *Code Sense*. The problem is that when Code Sense kicks in for code completion, sometimes the source code text below the line I'm working on goes "crazy". If I continue typing, the problem gets worse, and after a while the source code is completely screwed up (funny colors, missing lines and characters, ...). Strange enough, the source code itself is unaffected, because when I select another source file and then go back to the one I was working on, everything looks fine again.

The problem can be seen in this screencast: http://www.screencast.com/t/OGY3NWE5

**Interesting facts:**

- This problem has occurred on 3 different machines, so it's not related to a corrupt installation.
- Sometimes it's fine for a while (up to one hour) after launching Xcode, but once it starts happening, it's getting worse and worse, until Xcode is restarted. Then it's fine again (for a while)

I've searched the web for similar experiences, and I can't find anything. I would think that it is a known problem, since it occurs on 3 different Macs here (both running 10.5 and 10.6).

Anyone having the same problems? Or a suggestion for fixing this?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring/7676487#7676487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally (kind of) fixed this problem by simply turning off ***Quick Help***. Previously, I left this on all the time, and it resulted in a very unstable code sense (to the point where Xcode simply became unusable).

This is not a real solution, but it should at least help people experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can be a real pain. I didn't find a 'fix for it as such, but I do a quick switch from implementation to header (or vice versa) and then back again using Command-option-up. The screen redraws and everything is fine again

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about it [here](http://idebuggerman.blogspot.com/2011/04/xcode-4-code-sense-failing.html)

My issue was with localization. if your XIB file is localized using xcode 4's, then it was failing for me. removing the localization worked, though not a proper solution.

Comment: How did you find that file that was failing?

Comment: well.. **narrowed** it down. :)