# Xcode not verifying code or suggesting classes in certain classes

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have a folder I imported into Xcode using the folder reference method. I'm having no trouble importing all the classes inside of it to other files and using them on the Storyboard however there is a quite annoying Xcode bug that makes it hard to do anything.

That Xcode suggestion system that has made me so fond of using Xcode and Objective C doesn't show up. So if I start to type "NS...." it doesn't recommend all the NS Classes! or Anything else for that matter.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I thought that maybe the index likely got broken and clearing your project's derived data ( in Xcode organiser ) but OP reported that didn't help so I removed my answer

Comment: I know its Xcode 4, but is this related to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469386/xcode-4-autocomplete-buggy