# xcode 5 syntax highlight not working for unit test file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode5, xctest

I have setup a unit test for my project. 
Initially i got stuck with errors during the compilation of the test file, finally i solved it and my tests now are working.

The problem now is that the syntax highlight is not working for the test file, only for that.
I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676487/561744) to solve this issue but no luck.
Removing the derived data of the project worked one time but then i closed xcode and when i reopened it there was no syntax highlight again.
Also i have reinstalled xcode 5 from App Store 2 days ago so this should be a fresh new install.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue went away when I added my Test target to the Test action in the Scheme editor (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme..).

See the picture at this post:

http://www.stewgleadow.com/blog/2011/10/30/adding-unit-tests-to-an-existing-ios-project/