# No error highlighting in test bundle in XCode 7.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my test bundle in an Objective-C iOS app, errors are not highlighted automatically (things like missing semicolon etc). I have to run the tests and then check the build log when the build fails.

Is that normal or have I messed up the configuration?  For the rest of the project, error highlighting works as expected.

Comment: Could you upload your project somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add the Test Target to the Test action in the Scheme editor.

In XCode 7.2:

1. Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
2. Select `Test` on the left.
3. If your test target is not listed under `Tests` on the right, click the plus sign on the button to add it.

I found [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507850/xcode-5-syntax-highlight-not-working-for-unit-test-file) answer after googling for `test target` instead of `test bundle`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure my way will work with you or not,
I had faced the same scenario and I had run my code on Xcode 5.1.1 and It showing the error.
or

And another reason that may be possible is you have dragged new library 
but not select target.
I am attaching image please have a look

[image]

Please let me know If it's working.