# xcode 5 project with cocoa pods won't highlight and autocomplete

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm having an issue with xcode 5, im using cocoa pods for a project, but when i open the .workspace file xcode doesn't autocomplete anything from foundation framework or uikit framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently after integrating CocoaPods.  This answer fixed me right up:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676487/1114876

Essentially, delete your derived data (the answer above has step-by-step instructions).