# iphone CATiledLayer not recognized as class?

Tags: iphone, pdf, zooming, catiledlayer

Im following the apple ZoomingPDFViewer example, I have the frameworks just as in the example, but when I write in xcode the class `CATiledLayer` doesnt get recognized in the edit area (no coming purple as a class, like in the example, and comand click on that word and doesnt recognize it), what am I missing ??

```
     CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
```

I build the project and get no error or warning, but why it doesnt recognize the class?

EDIT>

changed project get info settings as suggested, but still not working!

- changed the compiler from GCC 4.2 to LLVM GCC 4.2.
- changed the Project Format to match the version of Xcode I'm using ("Xcode 3.2-compatible").
- click "Rebuild Code Sense Index" button.

still not working!,
what could it be?, it appears working in apple sample code, but not in mine?? What would I be missing?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure if you saw below, but found some interesting info that may help, check the comments thread...hope it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [xcode code sense color/completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1627033/239318)

Comment: Hmm, per http://www.openradar.appspot.com/7338181, try turning off the static analyzer in your project build settings, if on.  Then rebuild CodeSense again.  This is Xcode 4.0.1, I assume?