# Xcode 4.1 editor text color problem

Tags: xcode

While I editing code, the editor window suddenly become unreadable. I attached a screenshot (Left window has the problem). It happens 2 or 3 times a week. I'm using Xcode 4.1 on Lion and color theme is Midnight.

It happens also when I using Basic theme. When I use Basic theme text color changed to white.

What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: I have experienced the same problem XCode 4.1 build 4B110 on Lion 10.7.1. I've tried a few different colour schemes and they all do it after a day or so. Swapping to any other theme and back seems to fix it. I also notice it's only on the buffer for some files - ie x.h is OK, x.m is mucked up.

Comment: Good to know that I'm not alone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That used to happen when I made a syntax error in the code, after I fixed it the problem went away. But this time it became permanent for some reason, and it really bothers me. I suggest you to check for warnings/ syntax errors but I also would like to hear a real solution for the problem.

Edit: Following solutions on this page helped: [xcode code sense color/completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627033/xcode-code-sense-color-completion-not-working)