# Xcode 5.1.1 is not showing colored syntax for new added files?

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and came across this weird problem.

When i add new files in Xcode, these files do not have the colored syntax, and auto complete doesn't work (in only these files, already existing files are ok).

I have tried solutions on these previously asked questions (deleted DerivedData from organizer)

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627033/xcode-code-sense-color-completion-not-working)

And it got even worse.... now even the already existed files stopped showing syntax in colors.

What should i do to make it work again?

Comment: Reinstall XCode if possible.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : That's the first thing i do whenever i encounter any weird problem... :)

Comment: @Avt : already did that. i even removed Xcode folder from Library->Developer and then installed xcode again. but nothing is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't validate your project to new settings. you should look into the list of warnings. there will be a warning about validating project settings.

I came across the same problem and updating to new settings solved it.

And also if you deleted previously added files. don't add them back. they won't have the syntax coloured. instead make a new class with a different name and copy the code from the original class. I don't really know, why this happens but this will solve your problem.