# XCode 6.3 autocomplete not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autocomplete

I'm learning basics of Objective-C and using XCode for writing code.
As you all know autocomplete option is perfect for new users that don't know (or remember) name of functions.

I have a problem with using autocomplete in XCode 6.3 couse its just.. not working - it is not showing anything or showing things that are not connected.

For example I just wrote simple few lines of code gusing NSMutableArray and NSEnumerator, when I'm trying to remind myself function/message 'nextObject' of NSEnumerator, XCode is not suggesting anything.

Here is a pic to show it:
[image]

Am I doing sth wrong or there is a way to fix it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode code sense color/completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627033/xcode-code-sense-color-completion-not-working)

Comment: I'm having the same issues with xcode 6.3

Answer (score 0):

It must be a temporary glitch. Happens to me almost all the time while Xcode is "indexing". You might be typing too fast and by the time Xcode gives indexing a break and looks for the auto-completion you might have types something for which there is no method (or something that you expected)
Also, for custom classes & method, make sure you have included the respective header files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that autocomplete does not work when there is an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for autoComplete not working can be anything. Do any one of the following to debug it

1. Check if there are errors and if so try to solve it and then check autoComplete. If any error is present in any of the line then autoComplete will not work for below code. Try autoComplete above the error incase you want to check.
2. If debugger does not throw any error then try commenting out the all lines and uncomment it from top to methods to recheck the autoComplete
3. Quit Xcode and Reopen it
4. Clear Derived data and then launch Xcode and check